# Update prompt on window change in tmux

Tags: command-line, tmux, prompt

Windows in tmux can easily become out of sync.  For example, in both windows I might have:

```
~/dir git:(master *) $
```

The `*` indicates changes.  Then I run `git commit` in one window, or change to another branch, etc.  This obviously updates the prompt in the window where I run the command, but when I change to the next window it still shows the prompt above.

This is easily corrected simply by pressing  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>, et. al., but I am wondering if there is a way to keep the prompts in sync.

Is there any way to do this naturally?  If not, is there any way to run a command automatically when changing to another window (for example `cd .`) to force a reload of the prompt?